# PHP & MySQL Bug

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

The code that follows is practice of me trying to establish a login page that checks username(email) & password with an existing account. I have a login page that submits the information, but once it goes to this second page for processing, it never gives me a successful login. Now I've commented out parts of the code and believe the bug lies somewhere in the while loop.

The code tries to take POSTed data from the form and compare it to a database called "registered" with table 'accounts'. There are 4 rows of data currently in the table with usernames 1, 12, 123, and 1234. All their passwords are 2. No matter my input, it gives me the same errors that I setup- 
"no such login in the system. please try again."
"Failed attempt."

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="format.css" />

<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Change localhost to match yours
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889", "root", "root", "registered");


$sql= "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE email ='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if ($password == $row["password"] ){
        echo "successfull login";
        echo "<script>window.location.href='session.php'</script>";
    }
}

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)==0)
{
echo "<p> no such login in the system. please try again. </p>";
}
else{
echo "successfully logged into system.";
echo "<script>window.location.href='session.php'</script>";
}

mysqli_close($connect);

echo "<p> Failed attempt. </p>"
?>
</html>
```

** Ok, I fixed the $result = mysql... -> $result = mysqli.... 
but I'm still getting the same errors.

** I changed mysql_affected_rows() -> mysql_affected_rows($connect)
still getting those errors

**mysql_close -> mysqli_close($connect);
ah still getting the errors

Thank you for your help though. Hopefully this will work out eventually.

Comment: From the manual for [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-affected-rows.php)  -> `Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.` You are looking for [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) -> `Gets the number of rows in a result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($connect, $sql);
```

should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Hold on there are more

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0)
```

should be

```
mysqli_affected_rows($connect)
```

and

```
mysql_close($con);
```

should be

```
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_affected_rows()
```

Should be:

```
mysqli_affected_rows($connect)
```